# Android 13 per-app language API does not work

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement the new Android 13 API to change language per-app directly from my app settings. Users can change it using a radio group.

The problem is that it works perfectly for Android API< 33 but not for the 33 itself.

On API 33, my activity recreates, but the language is still the same. Language change from the system settings does not work as well.

```
        val selectedLocale = when (view.getId()) {
            R.id.radioBtnEn -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en")
            R.id.radioBtnCz -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("cs")
            else -> LocaleListCompat.getEmptyLocaleList()     //default language
        }
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(selectedLocale)
```

I also have `locales_config.xml` and `resConfigs` just like in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#known-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was due to my old unused code, which I used to handle language changes manually before this API.

These methods probably broke configuration changes after picking language in the system settings.

```
override fun getDelegate()
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration)
```

Now it works as intended!